# How to manipulate order of Scenario Execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

I have some features to test using Gherkin and Cucumber. The thing is that the execution is random, and since, for example, the first scenario is creating elements on the page, second one is looking for them and third moving them, all test are crashing cause the execution is going like: nº9 firts, then 8, then 2, then...

I am not using execution tags, or if I use them, I'm using it above "Feature:" to make sure all scenarios are running

Anyone could bring some light here?

Answer (score 6):

General consensus within the test automation community is that your automated tests should be able to run independently. That is, tests should be runnable in any given order and the result of a test should not depend on the outcome of one or more previous tests. Try changing the architecture of your test cases.

It is possible to run tests in specific order using JUnit or TestNG.
https://www.ontestautomation.com/running-your-tests-in-a-specific-order/

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! So are u suggesting that i should put all the CRUD operation in the same scenario? Will be a loooong scenario to do so